# How to Read CSV into Data Frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file of format:

[1,2,3,4] [1,2,3,4] [1,2,3,4] .....

When I read this file in using:

`x_train = pd.read_csv('Normal_objects.csv', header = 0)`

It creates a Dataframe of multiple rows and one single column. Contained within this column is a series [1,2,3,4].

How do I go about reading in this file in a manner I would expect ie. for this example:

```
[1,2,3,4]
[1,2,3,4]
[1,2,3,4]
```

It would be a dataframe of three rows and four columns

Comment: [1,2,3,4] [1,2,3,4] [1,2,3,4] is not a valid CSV File. A valid CSV file would be: 1,2,3,4\n1,2,3,4\n1,2,3,4. If you try reading the valid csv using read_csv, it will work. Else, you first need to preprocess your file to come up with correct format, and then read it.